# Is there any support for SVG image in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

Does react native contain any library which supports SVG images for both iOS and android.

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg

Answer (score 0):

you can try react-native-svg you can check the package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)